# How to make weighted graph from dictionary?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I'm trying to make a weighted graph from a dictionary. i think the way I get my data is making it difficult.
I get my data as follows:

```
graph = {}

graph["A"] = {}
graph["A"] ["B"] = 1 
graph["A"] ["C"] = 3 
graph["A"] ["D"] = 2 

graph["B"] = {} 
graph["B"] ["D"] = 7
graph["B"] ["F"] = 5

graph["C"] = {}
graph["C"] ["E"] = 5

graph["D"] = {}
graph["D"] ["B"] = 7
graph["D"] ["E"] = 1

graph["E"] = {}
graph["E"] ["F"] = 4

graph["F"] = {}
```

The parent node is a dictionary which stores its neighbour which has the weight of the edge.

I can make an unweighted graph just fine using networkx:

```
for k, v in graph.items():
    G.add_edges_from(([(k,t) for t in v]))
```

But I can't think of a way to add the weight to the edge.
Unfortunately i can't edit the way I get my data, and that is the only option I can think of to get it to work. Please help

Comment: `I can't think of a way to add the weight to the edge.` - you don't know how to weight a networkx edge? or you don't know how to get the weight from your *graph*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming G is your Graph:

```
graph = {}

graph["A"] = {}
graph["A"] ["B"] = 1 
graph["A"] ["C"] = 3 
graph["A"] ["D"] = 2 

graph["B"] = {} 
graph["B"] ["D"] = 7
graph["B"] ["F"] = 5

graph["C"] = {}
graph["C"] ["E"] = 5

graph["D"] = {}
graph["D"] ["B"] = 7
graph["D"] ["E"] = 1

graph["E"] = {}
graph["E"] ["F"] = 4

graph["F"] = {}

for k,v in graph.items():
    for l, w in v.items():
        print(k, l, w)
        G.add_edge(k,l, weight=w)
```

[Documentation](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.Graph.add_edge.html#networkx.Graph.add_edge)

Answer (score 0):

Using your example `graph`. Combine the keys in `graph` with each item in its value. Use [.add_weighted_edges_from](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/graph.html#methods) to add the edges.

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.Graph()

for k, v in graph.items():
    edges = [(k,b,w) for b,w in v.items()]
    print(edges)
    #G.add_weighted_edges_from(edges)
    G.add_weighted_edges_from((k,b,w) for b,w in v.items())
```

---

```
>>>
[('A', 'B', 1), ('A', 'C', 3), ('A', 'D', 2)]
[('B', 'D', 7), ('B', 'F', 5)]
[('C', 'E', 5)]
[('D', 'B', 7), ('D', 'E', 1)]
[('E', 'F', 4)]
[]

---
>>> for edge in G.edges.data():
...     print(edge)
('A', 'B', {'weight': 1})
('A', 'C', {'weight': 3})
('A', 'D', {'weight': 2})
('B', 'D', {'weight': 7})
('B', 'F', {'weight': 5})
('C', 'E', {'weight': 5})
('D', 'E', {'weight': 1})
('F', 'E', {'weight': 4})
```